# Casting Object to String v/s Casting object to Character

Tags: java, object, casting

I have a generic implementation of a Stack. An object of this Stack has the name stak and is of the type `Character`.

I tried

```
if ( ( ((String)(stak.head).equals("{")) && (str.charAt(i)=='}') )  { /* do something */}
```

The code compiles correctly but it gives me following error on runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character can
not be cast to java.lang.String
        at One.main(One.java:36)
```

However, the following code works:

```
if ( ((Character)(stak.head) == '{') && (str.charAt(i)=='}') )  { /* do something */}
```

Can you please explain why doesn't the character object get cast into String?

Comment: `Can you please explain why doesn't the character object get cast into String?` .. because Character does not extend from String

Comment: If you're doing something with Generics, you shouldn't be casting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because `Character` is not a `String`, doesn't fall in the common hierarchy and hence doesn't allow casting. You can try casting a `List` to an `ArrayList` because the compiler knows that they share a common inheritance tree. Also, if you have a generic implementation of a `Stack`, you really shouldn't be relying on concrete types like this so I wonder what you've got in your code.

Also, `{` getting *converted* to `Character` is not about casting but about auto-boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

A **char** is a *primitive* but a **String** is an *object*.

The **char** must be passed to a constructor in order to create an object of type **String**. (**Cast** doesn't create an object)

Comment: He doesn't have a `char` primitive, nor is he trying to cast one to something.

Comment: If he have `(stak.head)` and he is comparing it with `{` so I guessed he has it as a `char`. And he added `String` in order to be able to compare two `String`s. That's why I thought `stak.head` returns `char`!

Comment: As he stated, and as the error explicitly states, `stak.head` is a `Character` object. If he was trying to cast a primitive it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You claim to be doing something with Generics, therefore it is unclear as to why you would be casting anything.

That being said, you say you're working with type `Character` and from the stack trace and your first example it appears that `stak.head` is indeed of type `Character`.

You can't cast that to a `String`; it isn't one. It's as simple as that. The two classes have nothing to do with each other. Your second example is completely redundant and unnecessary as `stack.head` *is* a `Character`

**Edit to add:** also worth mentioning is that `Character` is a special class in Java that is a wrapper around the primitive `char`. When you say

```
if (stack.head == '{' ... )
```

The content of `stack.head` is *auto-unboxed* to a `char` and then compared to `'{'`. The single quotes denote a `char` literal.

Answer (score 0):

`Can you please explain why doesn't the character object get cast into String?`

This is because Character does not extend from String

In all probability what you should be using is a `Deque` instead of a custom implementation of Stack or the `java.util.Stack`

Sample code which prevents the issue that you are seeing :

```
    Deque<Character> charStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    charStack.addFirst('A');
    charStack.addFirst('B');
    System.out.println(charStack.pop()); //prints B
    charStack.addFirst("C"); //Avoids the String trap with a compilation error
```